# Properties and equation driven UI

Tags: c#

I have a project that requires me to specifiy a UI with TextBoxes. I'd like to use properties in order to avoid writing a bunch of UI specific code, and have chosen to use `Binding` and `TwoWay` to update the various properties for each field.

Lets say I have a basic equation:

X + Y * 50

The sum of this value will exist in one TextBox and the variables X and Y will exist in other TextBoxes. When the user sets these variable fields, NotifyPropertyChanged is called.

```
private string _X = "1";
public string X
{
    get
    {
        return _X;
    }
    set
    {
        _X = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("X");
    }
}
```

The `PropertyChanged` delegate is setup such that when `OnPropertyChanged` is called it will notify the other properties that depend on `X` for example.

*registering source property such that it notifies the dependent property it changed, which works*

`public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };`

The equation sum, `SUM`, property will then be notified of the change on `X`. In this case the `Get` method is called on the `SUM` property.

```
private string _SUM;
public string SUM
{
    get
    {
       // I need to update the SUM and then notify properties that depend on it.
       _SUM = X + Y * 50;
        return _SUM;
    }
    set
    {
        _SUM = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("SUM");
    }
}
```

Now my issue I'm having is, how can I update the `SUM` property and then update the properties that depend on the `SUM` property when only the `Get` method is called in `SUM`? I can't call `OnPropertyChanged("SUM")` because thats cyclical and that will not work.

Answer (score 0):

I think your missing the idea....

Your SUM property should look like this;

```
public string SUM
{
    get
    {
       return X + Y * 50;
    }
}
```

And then in your dependant fields, you would mark this as changed;

```
public string X
{
    get
    {
        return _X;
    }
    set
    {
        _X = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("X");
        OnPropertyChanged("SUM");
        OnPropertyChanged("MULT"); // Edit based on comment
    }
}
```

You can't update X and Y based on SUM, because there are multiple values that X and Y could take to provide a given sum... I think you need to rethink your design, or clarify your question.

Comment: So my issue is, how do I update `MULT`, a new property, that depends on `SUM`. So you then change`X` which notifies `SUM`, `SUM` then notifies  `MULT`. All while updating the GUI and the set value of each property. Could you expand on the above example I gave, because I'm having trouble seeing what I need to do inside the set or get of `SUM` to update `MULT`

Comment: Would `SUM`s get have to set it self and inside the set, `MULT` gets notified?

Comment: One way would just be to notify MULT changed in X and Y as well... See edit. A better way would be to use a MVVM framework which takes care of chained calcualted properties ( or a simple extension like this one: https://philchuang.com/mvvm-pain-points-chaineddependentcalculated-properties/) Note, I haven't used that class but it looks like it does what you want. Research the various MVVM Frameworks and consider using one of them

Comment: I wouldn't have SUM or MULT set anything, they shouldn't even have backing fields. They are calculations, not stored data, so they should only have getters - which do the calculation that property represents